# I am training model with yolov3 but it is not detecting the object.How ı can train to detect custom data?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, yolo

I'm using yolov3. I want to detect the cylindrical barrels in the picture below.[The barrel which ı want to detect](https://r.resimlink.com/tzSAbur_Xy.png).I used 1500 images for training and tagged them in yolo format. Then I trained them in google colab.[The loss chart of the model I trained](https://r.resimlink.com/fC0oqMp7h.png).

## **This my cfg file:**

```
[net]
# Testing
#batch=1
#subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=64
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 2000
policy=steps
steps=1800,1600
scales=.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear


[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

# Downsample

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[shortcut]
from=-3
activation=linear

######################

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=1024
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=18
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 6,7,8
anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
classes=1
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1


[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 61



[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=512
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=18
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
classes=1
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1



[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 36



[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
filters=256
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=18
activation=linear


[yolo]
mask = 0,1,2
anchors = 10,13,  16,30,  33,23,  30,61,  62,45,  59,119,  116,90,  156,198,  373,326
classes=1
num=9
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1
```

## **This is my prediction code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

net = cv2.dnn.readNet('/content/drive/MyDrive/yolo_custom_model_Training/backup/yolov3_last.weights', '/content/drive/MyDrive/yolo_custom_model_Training/darknet/cfg/yolov3.cfg')

classes = ["Barrel"]


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/MyDrive/yolo_custom_model_Training/fabrika.mp4')
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(100, 3))

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []

    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.2:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)

                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.2, 0.4)

    if len(indexes)>0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i],2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
            cv2.putText(img, label + " " + confidence, (x, y+20), font, 2, (255,255,255), 2)

    cv2_imshow( img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
```

My question is, the loss function of my model is falling, this is fine. But when I run the prediction code, it cannot detect any barrels? What can I do? (By the way, the pictures I used in the training have 250x250 dimensions and 1400x1400 ones.)

I trained my model by making some changes in cfg. In my first training, the number of pictures I used for training was 500, I increased it to 1500, but my model cannot make predictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to collect more images. 1500 is less to detect your object. collect again more images in different situations (from up, from far, from left, another backgrounds, etc ...). you can use yolov5 also which is better than yolov3.

```
git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git
cd yolov5
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

in yolov5 you will work with pytorch. in yolov5 accuracy and speed will be faster.
in documentation you can see how you can train your custom object: `https://docs.ultralytics.com/tutorials/train-custom-datasets/`

Comment: Thank you very very much.I used yolov5 and performance and accuracy is very good.Thankss

Comment: Great! Good luck to your codes